# CSS: make parent div exactly (in pixels) the same height as child

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` containing child `<img>` element:

```
<div class="wrapperdiv">
  <img src="blob" class="myimg">
</div>
```

Now, I want the `<div>` to have the same height as `<img>`.

More elaborately, my goal is to have div with img inside to have exactly the same position as if there was only img without wrapper div!

I've tried setting `height: auto` to the `<div>`, but while it sets the height to roughly same as `<img>`, it is larger by 1 pixel, and I'd like them to absolutely equal.

Comment: display: block for the image and no height for the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Justin Trevein, I have prepared one working demo on the basis of comment provided by @fcalderan. I hope this will be helpful.

> This DEMO is related to show only Height, and not a width.

```css
.wrapperdiv {
  background-color: green;
}

.wrapperdiv img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperdiv">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg" class="myimg"/>
</div>
```

Thanks, Jignesh Raval

Comment: Thanks, switching img display to block (and accounting for related changes) did the thing.

Answer (score 2):

set css :

```
.myimg { display: block ;}
```

and

```
.wrapperdiv { height: unset;}
```

Comment: Why height:unset instead of height:auto?

Comment: Just another method -- makes sure not to inherit any sizing from a parent element. So just a different way that works.